# Update UI Progress bar from external method

Tags: c#, wpf

So this is my first foray into using delegates, events, Backgroundworkers, WPF...pretty much everything is new.  I have an external class that runs a long running method that I would like to report progress on:

```
public class ShortFileCreator
{
    public void CreateShortUrlFile(string outputfilepath)
    {         
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
                //work work work processing file
                if (ReportProgress != null)
                {
                //report progress that a file has been processed
                    ReportProgress(this, new ProgressArgs {TotalProcessed = numberofurlsprocessed
                                                         , TotalRecords = _bitlyFile.NumberOfRecords});
                }
        }
    }

    public delegate void ReportProgressEventHandler (object sender, ProgressArgs args);

    public event ReportProgressEventHandler ReportProgress;

    public class ProgressArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int TotalProcessed { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my WPF Form, I want to kickoff the CreateShortUrlFile method and update the form's progress bar.

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var shortFileCreator = new ShortFileCreator();           

        _worker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };

        shortFileCreator.ReportProgress += ShortFileCreator_ReportProgress;

        _worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            _bitlyFileWorker.CreateShortUrlFile(saveFileDialog.FileName);
        };

        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    protected void ShortFileCreator_ReportProgress(object sender, ShortFileCreator.ProgressArgs e)
    {
        //update progress bar label
        txtProgress.Content = String.Format("{0} of {1} Records Processed", e.TotalProcessed, e.TotalRecords);
        //update progress bar value
        progress.Value = (double) e.TotalProcessed/e.TotalRecords;
    }
```

However when I run this, it processes one line and then I get the exception: The calling thread cannot access this object because another thread owns it.  What other thread owns this? Shouldn't the ReportProgress event return ProgressArgs to any subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because UI controls like the `ProgressBar` and `TextBox` can not be touched by another thread, in this case you are trying to update them from the `BackgroundWorker` thread.

A way around this is to `Invoke` the call back to the UI thread, you can do this using the `Dispatcher`

```
protected void ShortFileCreator_ReportProgress(object sender, ShortFileCreator.ProgressArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
       //update progress bar label
       txtProgress.Content = String.Format("{0} of {1} Records Processed", e.TotalProcessed, e.TotalRecords);
       //update progress bar value
       progress.Value = (double) e.TotalProcessed/e.TotalRecords;
    });
}
```